# conditional attribute based on view port

Tags: typescript, ionic3, angular5

I set an ion-row attribute on my ion-card like this:

```
<ion-card ion-row></ion-card>
```

How can I make that `ion-row` attribute conditional based on my `$grid-breakpoints`?

So I want to add ion-row property when it is opened on mobile and otherwise I will not add this class.